# Equivalent condition for finite Nilpotent group

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, nilpotent-groups

Prove that a finite group $G$ is nilpotent if and only if whenever $a, b \in
G$ with $gcd(o(a), o(b)) = 1$, then $ab = ba$.

I know that a finite group G is nilpotent iff it is a direct product of its sylow subgroups.

$(\implies)$ Let G be nilpotent. So, it is a direct product of its sylow subgroups.

$\therefore G=P_{1}\times P_{2}\times \ldots \times P_{k}$  i.e. $G=P_{1}P_{2}\ldots P_{k}$ where each $P_{i}\lhd G \;\forall\,i\in \{1,2,\ldots,k\}$, and $(P_{1}P_{2} \ldots P_{i})\cap P_{i+1}=\{e\} \;\forall\,i\in \{1,2,\ldots,k\}$.

Consider $a,b \in G$ such that $gcd(o(a),o(b))=1$

Case 1: If $a=e \;\; or \;\; b=e$

There is nothing to prove in this case

Case 2: If $a\neq e\neq b$

If $a,b\in P_{i}, \; sylow\;p_{i}-subgroup$ for some $i$, then $gcd(o(a),o(b))\geq p_{i}>1$. Hence, a contradiction.

$\therefore a\in P_{i}, b\in P_{j},\; i\neq j$

Also, $P_{i}\cap P_{j} = \{e\}$

So, $aba^{-1}b^{-1}\in P_{i}\cap P_{j} $. 
Hence, $ab=ba$

$(\impliedby)$ Here if I prove that each of the sylow subgroups of G is normal in G, and I already have trivial intersection for each sylow subgroup of distinct primes. So, I would have G as the direct product of sylow subgroups which would imply G is nilpotent.

I am not able to think how to prove the normality part. Please give some hints.

Also, please check the forward implication.

Thanks!

Comment: Your proof of the only if part is incomplete. You have only considered the situation where $a$ and $b$ both lie in Sylow subgroups.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for pointing that out. Thanks!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for providing the link. It was really helpful.